# Dnsmasq broken after upgrade to Bionic: works, but takes ~30 seconds to resolve any query

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, ubuntu-18.04

my dnsmasq configuration got broken after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04.

- systemd-resolved is enabled and running
- dnsmasq is enabled and running

Any DNS query to the outside world will hang for some 30 seconds before succeeding. Queries to my local hosts (anything.mylocal) will succeed immediately.

If I stop dnsmasq (i.e. `service dnsmasq stop`), then all DNS queries to the outside world will work immediately (but .mylocal, of course, not).

In: /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
address=/.mylocal/127.0.0.1
```

In: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
...
# dns=dnsmasq
...
```

Uncommenting the dns= line will prevent ANY dns query.

In: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=no
```

In: /etc/resolv.conf

This file is a link to: ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf, which contains:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

In: /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

One noticeable difference with the output of `systemd-resolve --status`:

- With dnsmasq running, the first line in Global reads: `DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1`
- With dnsmasq stopped, this line is absent, there is no global DNS Server, and the first useful server is defined in  the Link 2 section, which specifies my default gateway (192.168.1.1)

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If resolv.conf is a link, then what does its target file contain?

Comment: It contains: nameserver 127.0.0.53
(I also edited the answer)

Comment: What tools are you using to test DNS queries? What "hosts" modules are enabled in /etc/nsswitch.conf?

Comment: Sorry, I clicked too quickly. I reported the nsswitch.conf content. As for the tests, I just do a ping to google.com. With dnsmasq it hangs for 30 seconds, without it it returns immediately.

Comment: Also added some output of systemd-resolve --status

Comment: Strongly suspect that both programs end up being configured with each other as the upstream server, resulting in a loop. dnsmasq gets its from resolv.conf, but I have no idea what adds that extra entry into systemd-resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... if you have any additional idea about debugging this, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

After a night's sleep ;-) this is what I came up with. I just manually added some public upstream servers (1.1.1.1 is CloudFlare's, 8.8.8.8 is Google's)

In: /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
address=/.mylocal/127.0.0.1
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.8.8
```

All the remaining files are left as in my question. Both systemd-resolved and dnsmasq are enabled and running.

This makes DNS queries work.

I still do not consider this as the correct answer, because I would prefer to use the DNS provided by the network, but at least it works...